# Error while loading pkl file using joblib

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pickle, joblib

Following [this](https://github.com/adithyaselv/face-expression-detect/blob/master/EmoDetect.py) post, I'm trying to execute the code using joblib. But I'm getting the following error:

```
classify=joblib.load("traindata.pkl")
```

> ValueError: You may be trying to read with python 3 a joblib pickle
>   generated with python 2. This feature is not supported by joblib.

In the [doc](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/externals/joblib/numpy_pickle.py), it's saying I'm using python3, that's why getting this error.

How to read the pkl file using python3?

Thank you!

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I am having the same problem.

Comment: @EvanLalo: I could not. But according to the answer it's not possible.

Comment: notice that one could devise a set of 2 python scripts: 1 in python2.7 to load the the dataset and export it in a ascii format, 1 in python3 to load the ascii format and save it as a more compact pickle file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cant!

> If you are switching between python versions, you will need to save a different joblib pickle for each python version.

https://pythonhosted.org/joblib/persistence.html#compatibility-across-python-versions

This is pretty hideous, but that's it.